# Is hiding <img> tag or set it in noscript SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, html, css, images

Is it possible to make `img` tag `display:none` and then add it with CSS `background`?

For example:

```html
<div style="background-image:url('image.png')">
   <img src="image.png" alt="description of image" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Assume with this Google search engine can detect tag same as adding `img` tag inside `noscript` (I find it in lazy load plugin doing this).

```html
 <nosript>
    <img src="image.png" alt="description of image" >
 </noscript>
```

So is it safe doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @JohnConde i want to use it with css instead showing it in img tag

Comment: So why have the image there at all then? Why put it there and then hide it?

Comment: @JohnConde so i can keep the alt

Comment: This is silly. Just use the normal image. That way you get the alt attribute and don't have SEO worries. It's a lot less code, too. Either way you're downloading the image. You're going out of your way for literally nothing.

Comment: How about adding background-image in external css bcoz it will do lazy load automatically if you use async tag. By using display:none the browser will still make HTTP request to image server.

Comment: Can you explain more about the benefits of "using an image with CSS"?